# Are there any caps that have wire leads that are in the pF range?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, components, capacitance

I am an electronics hobbyist and enthusiast, and I want to build an oscillator for fun and to learn how it works.

I want to try different values of caps, such as mF, nF, etc. But I want to also try the pF range as well. What I have found is that all the caps on the market that are in the pF range are for PCBs (to my understanding). They look like [this](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/yageo/CC0402DRNPO9BN6R2/8024813?utm_adgroup=Yageo&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Smart%20Shopping_Supplier_Yageo&utm_term=&productid=8024813&gclid=CjwKCAjwy42FBhB2EiwAJY0yQiTslD0LVi6SIs029QVHDT4D2oAoBTfFSM4j7RSucFep9s35W9DcnBoCF8QQAvD_BwE). It seems to be rather difficult to find what I need.

I don't want to get into PCBs as that subject is rather dull for me.

---

Basically, my requirements are:

- pF range caps
- That have wire leads (and not connections like in the one that I linked)
- That does not require the use of PCBs (can be used without putting them on a PCB)

---

It would be great if all of these would be met. I am willing to create my own caps that have these requirements and if you can share any advice on how to build them or point to any resources, that would be fantastic.

I just hope I am not looking for unicorns or that I am asking for too much here.

Thank you.

Comment: Standard silver mica capacitors! I have loads of them, ranging from 5 pf to 500 pf. Should be available still!

Comment: If you're thinking of using them in breadboards be prepared for the breadboard having more capacitance than the pF capacitors.

Comment: @Transistor Yes, I would like to build my circuit on a breadboard. Would the breadboard having more capacitance be a problem for me if I were to use the pF caps on it?

Comment: Yes. You won't get the frequencies you expect. You'll have to allow for the capacitance between breadboard strips. I don't know the values.

Comment: @EdV Thank you for that! I found a whole site that sells them, I am in luck. They also seem to have a large voltage threshold as well (~500V), which is very nice.

Comment: @Transistor I will do my research on that and figure it out. Worst case scenario, I would have to build my circuit on my bare table.

Comment: Take a look at "Manhattan" style prototyping.  A little more involved but cuts down on stray capacitance.

Comment: @vir Sure thing, I will take a look at it.

Comment: @shocked while vir is right, and Manhattan-style soldering can have advantages in terms of stray capacitance, be **very** wary of amateur radio circuit enthusiasts that promise fantastic results through them. There is a lot of snake oil believing going on in the Ham radio community, and one of their favorite snake oils is couple-of-MHz circuits minimizing stray capacitance through Manhattan wiring measurably "a lot" compared to a sensibly built PCB. There is really not that much magic going on: bring two conductors close together, they form a capacitor. Else, they don't.

Comment: That effect goes inversely proportional with the distance and proportional with the area of surfaces. That's all. Whether or not your components are being randomly oriented in a small box and have their leads point up makes very little difference to capacitance. It does make a difference when it comes to being unintended antennas, but that happens at higher frequencies only.

Comment: Crazy thing about what you're seeking is that the very act of using an oscilloscope to measure the oscillation frequency will wreck the oscillator due to scope probe capacitance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These definitely are available; larger pF values as ceramic, smaller as film capacitors. Need to look at a proper electronics store like Farnell/element14, mouser or digikey!

> I just hope I am not looking for unicorns

No! But:

> That does not require the use of PCBs (can be used without putting them on a PCB)

Uff. You have to realize everything that consists of two separate conductors can and will act as a capacitor. Therefore, things like breadboard contact rows will very much do. Their so-called parasitic capacitance will be larger than a handful pF, and the same will apply to long flying cables etc.

When building high-frequency oscillators, your mechanical way of building it becomes part of where its component values come from. I think this is really a good motivation to learn how to use at the very least perfboard to solder your own, short-wired, low-capacitance circuitry.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will look at those companies for what they have to sell. I will also consider perfboards as an option too.

Comment: NP0/C0G are temperature stable type ceramics and can be more accurate with tolerance options

Comment: Much appreciated, @Tony, but in all honesty, don't think temperature stability will be an early issue here. (If you want to build an exact, stable oscillator without external control loop, it's probably going to be quartz- or SAW-based if it is in the frequency ranges you'd achieve with pF capacitors, so if Shocked was after building a *good* oscillator, they wouldn't be trying to go for an oscillator design where the capacitance is critical when that capacitance approaches parasitics)

Comment: Yes but you need <10pF to null the error.   Two #24 PVC hookup wires twisted tightly is about 10 pf per inch.... as long as U are <1/2 the SRF